# How to add value to html() with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What am I doing wrong that this jQuery isn't doing anything?

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
```

In body

```
<p id="somediv"></p>
<script>
var arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
$(document).ready(function(){
$("somediv").html("before loop");
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
       $("somediv").html(value);
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#somediv").html(value);
```

You are missing the # in front of your ID selector

Answer (score 1):

You are missing id selector `#` in all cases:

```
$("#somediv").html(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed **#** prefix in all in your code. if you put .html() means it display last value only visible in your case use append

```
$("#somediv").append(value);
```